# how to get value of default checked checkbox in alert dialog android java

Tags: java, android, checkbox, android-alertdialog

```
final List < CharSequence > checkedsurveylist = new ArrayList < CharSequence > ();
final JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
final boolean[] checkedItems = new boolean[jsonArray.length()];
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
  String syncstatus = "";
  if (obj.get("syncstatus").toString().matches("1")) {
    syncstatus = "Not yet synchronized";
    checkedItems[i] = false;
  } else if (obj.get("syncstatus").toString().matches("2")) {
    syncstatus = "Synchronized";
    checkedItems[i] = true;
  }
  checkedsurveylist.add("(" + obj.get("sysid").toString() + ")" + obj.get("surveytitle").toString() + " - " + syncstatus);
}


System.out.println("checkedItems " + checkedItems);
final List < String > mSelectedItems = new ArrayList < String > ();
final List < Integer > mSelectedItemsindex = new ArrayList < Integer > ();
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Connect_server.this);
builder.setTitle("Survey List")
  .setMultiChoiceItems(checkedsurveylist.toArray(new CharSequence[checkedsurveylist.size()]), checkedItems,
    new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() {


      @Override
      public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
        int which, boolean isChecked) {

        checkedsurveylist.toArray()[which] = isChecked;
        // Get the current focused item
        String currentItem = checkedsurveylist.get(which).toString();

        // Notify the current action
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
          currentItem + " " + isChecked, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (isChecked) {

          mSelectedItems.add(checkedsurveylist.get(which).toString());
          mSelectedItemsindex.add(which);
        } else if (mSelectedItems.contains(which)) {
          mSelectedItemsindex.remove(Integer.valueOf(which));

          mSelectedItems.remove(Integer
            .valueOf(which));
        }
      }
    });
// Set the positive/yes button click listener
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    // Do something when click positive button
    System.out.println("asdasdasd " + mSelectedItemsindex.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < mSelectedItemsindex.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println("asdasdasd " + checkedsurveylist.get(i).toString());
    }

  }
});
```

This is my code for making a list with checkbox in alert dialog box. It can have multiple selection. my problem is I can get the value of default checked checkbox. I can only get the value if the checkbox is manually check by the user.

**How to get the value of checkbox if it is by default checked.**

`Update`

```
ListView lv = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
   System.out.println("asd" + "pos = " + lv.getCheckedItemPosition());
   System.out.println("asd" + "which = " + which);
```

I used this but on click of OK button but i get -1 on position and -1 on which

Comment: calling `isChecked()` on the CheckBox's instance ?

Comment: can you tell where and how @Blackbelt

Comment: Why not just add the pre-checked items to your `ArrayList`s in the `for` loop? If you don't wanna do that, `AlertDialog#getListView().getCheckedItemPositions()` will return a `SparseBooleanArray` with the checked positions.

Comment: @MikeM. see update for `getCheckedItemPosition()` i used it in click of OK button with in the alert dialog box

Comment: Look again. `getCheckedItemPositions()`, plural.

Comment: @MikeM. it worked i used this `ListView lv = ((AlertDialog) dialog).getListView();
                                        SparseBooleanArray checkedItems = lv.getCheckedItemPositions();` can you post it as answer so that i can close this OP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In an `AlertDialog` with list items, you can get the default `ListView` with the `getListView()` method.

In a `ListView` with a multiple choice mode, the `getCheckedItemPositions()` will return a `SparseBooleanArray` with the checked items.

Put those together, and you can get all of the selected items, including those checked at showing.

Comment: Mike one more question is there a way to add an attribute data on each list item. example a data that is not shown on the list but can be access when selecting the checked item. for example adding `.setTag()`?

Comment: Well, not directly. What I'd do is probably make a simple custom class that `implements CharSequence`, add your `setTag()`/`getTag()` methods and field to it, and use that class for the `checkedsurveylist`. As long as the `toString()` method returns the concatenated `String` you're adding to the list now, it would be a transparent change, as far as the UI goes.

Comment: mate one more question i wanted to disable the checkbox that are pre checked i used `lv.getChildAt(checkedItems.keyAt(i)).setEnabled(false);` this inside `if (checkedItems.get(i)) {` any  idea how to disable pre checked box?

Comment: I doubt you can easily get the behavior you want with an `AlertDialog`. You can set a custom `ListAdapter` on an `AlertDialog`, but I'm pretty sure default behavior is for it to close after clicking an item, so the multi-checks probably won't work. It's probably gonna be easier if you just make your own custom `Dialog`. I'll let ya know if I think of a way to do it simply with `AlertDialog`, but I'm thinking there's not.